# Android - Send data using shared preference not working

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and i am just trying to send some data from one activity to another using Shared Preference but my code doesn't works.

This is the activity i am entering data in.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private  Button  BTN;
    private EditText EDTXT,EDTXT2,EDTXT3;
    private CheckBox CHKBX;
    private final String mName = "Middle Name";
    private final String fName = "First Name";
    private final String lName = "Last Name";
    private final String isReg = "Is Registered";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    CHKBX=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    EDTXT=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EDTXT2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EDTXT3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(CHKBX.isChecked()){

                setPreferenceData();

                Intent INT = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SharedPreferenceData.class);
                startActivity(INT);

            }

        }
    });
}

public void setPreferenceData(){

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();

    spEditor.putBoolean(isReg, CHKBX.isChecked());
    spEditor.putString(fName, EDTXT.getText().toString());
    spEditor.putString(mName, EDTXT2.getText().toString());
    spEditor.putString(lName, EDTXT3.getText().toString());
    spEditor.commit();


}
```

This is the activity i want to pass data in.

```
public class SharedPreferenceData extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView TXTVW,TXTVW1,TXTVW2,TXTVW3;
private final String fName = "First Name";
private final String mName = "Middle Name";
private final String lName = "Last Name";
private final String isReg = "Is Registered";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared_preference_data);

    TXTVW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TXTVW1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TXTVW2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TXTVW3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    getSharedPreferencesData();

}

public void getSharedPreferencesData(){

    SharedPreferences spf = this.getSharedPreferences("My Pref",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    TXTVW.setText("First Name:" + spf.getString(fName,""));
    TXTVW1.setText("Middle Name:" + spf.getString(mName,""));
    TXTVW2.setText("Last Name:" + spf.getString(lName,""));
    TXTVW3.setText("Is Registered:" + spf.getBoolean(isReg,true));

}
```

Comment: Why are your preference names different ("MyPref" vs. "My Pref")? Why are you using `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data within the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SharedPreferenceData.class);
intent.putExtra(isReg, CHKBX.isChecked());
intent.putExtra(fName, EDTXT.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra(mName, EDTXT2.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra(lName, EDTXT3.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then read it inside `onCreate` (in SharedPreferenceData):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
TXTVW.setText("First Name:" + intent.getStringExtra(fName,""));
TXTVW1.setText("Middle Name:" + intent.getStringExtra(mName,""));
TXTVW2.setText("Last Name:" + intent.getStringExtra(lName,""));
TXTVW3.setText("Is Registered:" + intent.getBooleanExtra(isReg,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the default SharedPreferences?

```
SharedPreferences spf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

By the way, it would be better if you had a Constants class where you place the constants to identify the data that you are sending:

```
public final class Constants {

    // SHARED PREFERENCES
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_F_NAME = "First Name";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_M_NAME = "Middle Name";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_L_NAME = "Last Name";
    public static final String SHARED_PREF_IS_REG = "Is Registered";
}
```

And then you get these constants like:

```
public void getSharedPreferencesData(){

    SharedPreferences spf = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    TXTVW.setText("First Name:" + spf.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_F_NAME,""));
    TXTVW1.setText("Middle Name:" + spf.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_M_NAME,""));
    TXTVW2.setText("Last Name:" + spf.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_L_NAME,""));
    TXTVW3.setText("Is Registered:" + spf.getBoolean(Constants.SHARED_PREF_IS_REG,true));

}
```